# How To Speed Up Looping TimeSeriesModelFit?

Tags: performance-tuning

I need to apply 'TimeSeriesModelFit' to successive subsets of a long list. A small scale example of this is given here.

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000]; 
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[
TimeSeriesModelFit[data[[1 + i ;; 200 + i]], "ARMA"], {i, 1, 
800}];]
{2.2379, Null}
```

I need to loop this hundreds and thousands of times and it takes a really long time on my laptop. Anyway to speed this up?

Comment: The only way I can imagine to speed this up, is by limiting the search space for the model. For example, you can specify limits on the orders `p` and `q` by specifying `{"ARMA", {0 ;; 2, 0 ;; 2}}`.